# check for a key within an object within an array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have an array of objects that I queried from my backend on parse.com.
My objects are messages.
Inside each of these messages, I have strings represented by keys.
I want to populate a UITableView by the conversationId which is a key contained by each message object.

How would I

1. check this array of objects for this certain key called conversationId contained by each object.
2. Then catagorize them based on that conversationId (say I have two messages that have the same conversationId, i would want to send them to the same tableviewcell)
3. retain all the other strings within that message object such as senderId, message body, etc. and send them along with the conversationId to a certain cell.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: Okay how do i do this
    if(messagesArray containsObject:objectForKey: @"conversationId"]) {
    list all of those conversationId's
    }

Comment: obviously i cant search an object with: "objectForKey:"